# Bitfinex seems to be cutting off the last 3 chars of my 95 char Monero address

Tags: address

Hi I'm trying to withdraw my Monero from Bitfinex, I've extensively googled this question and I haven't found anyone else mentioning it so I assume its not a fault on Bitfinex's end.

I have this Monero address: 47abaPTX3gSFZTMoibeMQ4UqAkvup4Gtb41ruGbu1CUgg92sFixMnFp1HcXbzmP7xPgeFRutz3XCfQ47XV56Rqh26gY4QAT

When I paste it into Bitfinex to withdraw it cuts off the last 3 chars (QAT in this case)
At first I thought maybe mymonero is generating an integrated address so I tried to split the address using monero_wallet_cli only to find it isn't an integrated address but a standard one.

I have tried a different address too, same issue.

Not sure how I can make the address shorter so that Bitfinex will accept it. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You sure it's actually cutting it (could you be copy/pasting not the whole thing or it's just not displaying the last 3 chars??). I'm pretty sure we'd here about this if it was some kind of bug, it's a pretty big exchange! I suggest triple checking you are copy/pasting the whole address first and then contacting their support if you are sure it's nothing you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yes I have checked about 5 times that I'm copying the right address. I guess I can ask support but I've heard they are really bogged down atm and I was sure it would be something people have already solved here.

Comment: It seems some of the Bitfinex withdrawal box obscures some of the address so it was being entered properly. I have a different issue now, 
Im getting the error: 
Invalid monero address (47abaPTX3gSFZTMoibeMQ4UqAkvup4Gtb41ruGbu1CUgg92sFixMnFp1HcXbzmP7xPgeFRutz3XCfQ47XV56Rqh26gY4QAT)

But on https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html I get the result:
 Does #14 equal #11?  Yes! This is a valid Standard XMR address. 


So it does appear the address is valid but something is wrong with bitfinex

Comment: @user9933 - Please contact their support in that case, as there may be a bug in their validation code.